# Kotlin/Android: rotation of custom googlemaps marker

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, rotation, marker

How will a marker rotate on googlemaps? Lite mode used. I've been trying quite a lot. Nothing works. This is my basis of inquiry, it looks quite right to me:

```
val marker = map.addMarker(
        MarkerOptions()
            .position(arrowPointPosition)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(
                IconGenerator(context).run {
                    setBackground(resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_head, null)) // also tried to wrap it into a layout
                    setRotation(33) // alternative A
                    makeIcon()
                }
            ))
            .anchor(0.5F, 0.5F)
            .rotation(33F) // alternative B
    )
```

Comment: Are you referring to when the map is rotated and the marker doesn't rotate with it?  I tried your code (with my own arrow head) - alternative B - and the icon is rotated initially just fine - except when rotating the map - use `flat` to have it "stick" to the surface of earth and rotate with map.

Comment: It uses the lite mode, so it does not rotate. I should mention that.

Comment: From lite mode docs: You can add a marker and respond to a click event. You can also add custom marker icons. It's not possible to make a marker draggable. **Markers on a lite mode map are flat, and they cannot be rotated.**

Comment: Also the `alternative A` `setRotation` is treated as a multiple of 90 degrees: `((x + 360) % 360) / 90` so your 33 equates to 0.  Try 90 as a test.